# Combine two .log files and write into a single log file with sorted list based on timestamp

Tags: c, file-system

I'm writing a C program called "mylogger". It is a simple program that merges several log files in order of timestamp.

For example, we have **server.log**:

```
#SERVER
DEBUG,2011-10-21 14:32:00,server starting
DEBUG,2011-10-21 14:32:01,server started
WARN,2011-10-21 14:32:10,client connected
DEBUG,2011-10-21 14:32:15,received string
INFO,2011-10-21 14:32:18,sent result
ERROR,2011-10-21 14:32:19,error sending
DEBUG,2011-10-21 14:32:22,client disconnected
```

and **client.log**:

```
#CLIENT
WARN,2011-10-21 14:32:09,session started
INFO,2011-10-21 14:32:14,calling server
ERROR,2011-10-21 14:32:20,error while calling
DEBUG,2011-10-21 14:32:21,disconnecting
```

Then when you type `./mylogger` in terminal, the program will read these two files and output a **combinedlogs.log** file:

```
DEBUG,2011-10-21 14:32:00,server starting
DEBUG,2011-10-21 14:32:01,server started
WARN,2011-10-21 14:32:09,session started
WARN,2011-10-21 14:32:10,client connected
INFO,2011-10-21 14:32:14,calling server
DEBUG,2011-10-21 14:32:15,received string
INFO,2011-10-21 14:32:18,sent result
ERROR,2011-10-21 14:32:19,error sending
ERROR,2011-10-21 14:32:20,error while calling
DEBUG,2011-10-21 14:32:21,disconnecting
DEBUG,2011-10-21 14:32:22,client disconnected
```

And here is all my code.

`main.c` reads the working directory (either specified or default current working directory), and there is a filter to make sure only read .log files in that directory. Then it opens files and passes the string from files to the function `parseLine` line by line, which will convert the string to objects. Then it inserts an object into a linked list and calls the function `sortList` to sort the linked list based on timestamp. Then it finally writes the resulting list into a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "structDef.h"
/* to remove warning comparison between pointer and iteger */
#include <unistd.h>

/*Return true when file name end with suffix .log*/
bool has_log_extension(char const *name)
{
    size_t len = strlen(name);
    return len > 4 && strcmp(name + len - 4, ".log") == 0;
}

/* Main driver */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char cwd[1024];
  char *pathName;
  loglist *head, *tail;
  head = tail = NULL;
  logline *i;
  logline j;
  if((i = (logline *)malloc(sizeof(logline))) == NULL) {
      printf("Allocation falild!\n");
      exit(1);
  }

  /* Get current working directory */
  if (argc == 1) {
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
      pathName = cwd;
    } else {
      perror("getcwd() error");
    }
  }

  /* Get directory from user input */
  else if (argc == 2) {
    pathName = argv[1];
    fprintf(stdout, "input working dir: %s\n", pathName);
  }

  /* Invalid user input from command line */
  else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error:  invalid No. of command line arguments.\n"); exit(1);
  }

  /* End of user input */

  /* Open .log files in specified directory (default is cwd). */
  struct dirent *entry;
  DIR *dp;

  dp = opendir(pathName);
  if (dp == NULL) 
  {
    perror("opendir");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Save filenames into a string array */
  int maxLogFiles = 16;
  char **logfiles = malloc(maxLogFiles * sizeof(char *));
  char filetoOpen[maxLogFiles][20];

  int fileCount = 0;
  while((entry = readdir(dp)))
    if (has_log_extension(entry->d_name)) {
      strcpy(filetoOpen[fileCount], entry->d_name);

      if(fileCount == maxLogFiles -1) {
        maxLogFiles *= 2;
      }
      fileCount++;
    }
  closedir(dp);

  /*Now its time to open the files*/
  int k;
  char * buffer = 0;
  long length;
  FILE *f;

  for(k = 0; k < fileCount; k++) {

    f = fopen (filetoOpen[k], "r");

    if(f == NULL) {
      printf("\n Unable to open %s \n", filetoOpen[k]);
    }

    if (f) {
      fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
      length = ftell (f);
      fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
      buffer = malloc (length);
      if (buffer) {
        fread (buffer, 1, length, f);
      }
      fclose (f);
    }

    if (buffer) {
      /* If the log file is not start with #, skip this log file */
      if(buffer[0] != '#') {
          printf("\nlogfile %s is not start with #. Skipped...\n", logfiles[0]);
          break;
      }

     char * curLine = buffer;
     while(curLine)
     {
        char * nextLine = strchr(curLine, '\n');
        if (nextLine) *nextLine = '\0';  /* Temporarily terminate the current line */
        i = parseLine(curLine);
        if(i != 0) {
          strcpy(j.level,  i->level);
          strcpy(j.timestamp,  i->timestamp);
          strcpy(j.message,  i->message);
          insert_node(&head, &tail, j);
        }
        if (nextLine) *nextLine = '\n';  /* Then restore newline-char, just to be tidy */ 
        curLine = nextLine ? (nextLine+1) : NULL;
     }
    }
  }

  sortList(head);


  printf("\n --Sorted list: \n");
  printLines(head);
  writeToFile(head);


  return 0;
}
```

The error handling in **main.c** is not strong enough I think.

**functionA.c**

```
/*
* This class implemented 2 methods
* 1. parseLine
* 2. print out the list to the console
*/

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "prototypeA.h"


void insert_node(loglist **h, loglist **t, logline v) {
    loglist *temp;
    if((temp = (loglist *)malloc(sizeof(loglist))) == NULL) {
        printf("Allocation falild!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    temp->line = v;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(*h == NULL) {
        *h = *t = temp;
    }
    else {
        (*t)->next = temp;
        *t = (*t)->next;
    }
} /* End of insert */



/*
* To construct a logline with 3 fields (Level, Timestamp, Message)
* based on the input string.
* This function allocates memory.
*/
logline* parseLine(char *line) {

    const char takeMyComma[] = ",";
    char *token;
    char subLine[3][100];
    int subLineIndex = 0;


    if (line[0] == '#') {
    //   printf("Header skiped.\n");
      return 0;
    }

    /* Get the first comma */
    token = strtok(line, takeMyComma);

    /* Walk through other commas */
    while(token != NULL) {
      strcpy(subLine[subLineIndex++], token);
      token = strtok(NULL, takeMyComma);
    }

    logline *i;
    if((i = (logline *)malloc(sizeof(logline))) == NULL) {
        printf("Allocation falild!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    strcpy(i->level, subLine[0]);
    strcpy(i->timestamp, subLine[1]);
    strcpy(i->message,  subLine[2]);
    return i;
}

/* Print all the lines contained in the list. */
void printLines(loglist* l) {
    if (l == NULL) {
    printf("The list is empty.\n");
    }
    else {
        // printf("Logs list : \n");
        while (l != NULL) {
            printf("%s %s %s\n", l->line.level, l->line.timestamp, l->line.message);
            l = l->next;
        }
    }
}/* End of print */


/* Print all the lines contained in the list. */
void writeToFile(loglist* l) {
    FILE *sortedLogs;

    if (l == NULL) {
    printf("The list is empty.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("\n Writing...\n");
        /* Create the file to write */
        if((sortedLogs = fopen("combinedlogs.log", "w")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file: combinedlogs.log \n");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* Write data */
        while(l != NULL) {
            fprintf(sortedLogs, "%s %s %s\n", l->line.level, l->line.timestamp, l->line.message);
            l = l->next;
        }

        /* Close file */
        if(fclose(sortedLogs) == EOF) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not close file: combinedlogs.log \n");
        }
        printf("\n Done! \n");
    }
}/* End of print */
```

**functionB.c**

```
/*
 * This class implemented sort the lists.
 */

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "prototypeB.h"

void swap(loglist *p1, loglist *p2)
{
    logline temp = p1->line;
    p1->line = p2->line;
    p2->line = temp;
}

loglist* sortList(loglist* inlist) {

  loglist *head = inlist;
  loglist *traverse;
  loglist *min;

  while(head->next) {
    min = head;
    traverse = head->next;
    while(traverse) {
      if (strcmp(min->line.timestamp, traverse->line.timestamp) > 0) {
        min = traverse;
      }
      traverse = traverse->next;
    }
    swap(head, min);
    head = head->next;
  }
}
```

**prototypeA.h**

```
/*
* The header file that contains the prototypes using
* in functionA.c
*/

#include "structDef.h"

void insert_node(loglist **h, loglist **t, logline v);
void print_list(loglist *h);
logline* parseLine(char *line);
void deleteList(loglist* l);
void printLines(loglist* l);
```

**prototypeB.h**

```
/*
* The header file that contains the prototypes using
* in functionB.c
*/
#include "structDef.h"
loglist* mergeLists(loglist* resultlist, loglist* inlist);
loglist* sortList(loglist* inlist);
```

`structDef.h`

```
/*
 * The linked list struct which will be used in functions
 */
typedef struct logline {
  char level[20];
  char timestamp[20];
  char message[100];
} logline;

typedef struct loglist {
  logline line;
  struct loglist *next;
} loglist;
```

**makefile**

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g
OBJECTS = main.o functionA.o functionB.o

mylogger: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o mylogger

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

Comment: Are you writing this for educational purposes?  If you just want the results, then consider `sort -u -t , -k 2 -k 1 *.log` instead (additionally with `-m` if the source files are themselves already sorted).

Comment: No, not for educational, just personal project for fun:D I will try your suggestion, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any guarantee that lines in the source log files are in sorted order for e.g if line A comes before B then timeStamp of line A is less than line B?
If yes then you can also merge log files using the idea of merge sort (open all the log files together and increase the line pointer one by one as per their order among all the line pointers of all the log files). 
Along with merge sort you can also leverage the benefit of dumping the already sorted lines time to time to final log file. This will also decrease the memory resource consumption of your program.
Even if the lines are not in not sorted order in source log files, you can insert lines in sorted order by traversing the list and putting the line at right place (instead of always inserting them at end and later on sorting them).